# how to use orderby by combining multiple tables in linq to entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

My Tables are,

1. Jobs
2. Emp.Reg.Details
3. Emp.Plans
4. Alertsdone
5. CntactsViewed

These are the tables..Normally the jobs list listed from **Jobs** table.. I compare from all other tables..

**My linq query**

```
public IQueryable<Job> GetJobs()
{
    return (from job in _db.Jobs
            from ep in _db.Emp.Plans
            from al in _db.Alertsdone
            from cvc in _db.CntactsViewed

            join emps in _db.Emp.Reg.Details on job.OrganizationId equals emps.EmployerId into e
            join alr in _db.Alertsdone on ep.Alerts equals alr.AlertsSent
            join cv in _db.CntactsViewedon ep.Resumes equals cv.ContactsViewed
            from emp in e.DefaultIfEmpty()

            orderby job.OrganizationId != -1 descending, job.OrganizationId != null descending
            orderby job.OrganizationId != -1 descending, emp.EmployerId == job.OrganizationId && alr.alertssent ==ep.alerts descending, job.CreatedDate descending
            select job);
}
```

If i give like this it shows empty page.. I am trying if the above condition is not there means it should order other choices like `orderby job.OrganizationId != -1 descending, job.OrganizationId != null descending`.. And also i put `from emp in e.DefaultIfEmpty()`... But where i missed? please help me...

Comment: *pertanyaannya kurang jelas bro/sis*. The `orderby` clause showing that you are ordering query result by boolean value (true/false), is that really what you meant to do?

Comment: yes.. I ordered correctly.. the boolean values are mean in my table